# Using SonarQube to flag uncaught exceptions in run loops

Tags: java, sonarqube

We are using SonarQube to analyze our Java code but we realized that at least with the default settings it doesn't flag run loops that don't do proper exception handling, for instance it won't complain about the following:

```
while(true) {
   someMethodThatMayThrowAnException();
}

//End of method
```

Is there any way to get it to flag code like this so it doesn't happen in the future?

Comment: That might be possible but you will need to precise what you are trying to achieve. Are you talking about exceptions declared in the throw clause of the method ?

Comment: Basically I want to make sure all exceptions are caught in a run loop inside the run method of a class that implements Runnable